# Numbering is replaced by "1"?

Tags: support

I just noticed a question that had two different numbered lists with different numbers but both were rendered as "1".  Screen shot:

[image]

Is this supposed to be happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's supposed to be happening:  – that's how Markdown [defines it](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list):

> It’s important to note that the actual numbers you use to mark the list have no effect on the HTML output Markdown produces.

It's probably one of the more debated features of Markdown, but it's indeed thusly defined in the “spec” (scare quotes because the Markdown spec is more of a “description of behaviour” than an actual specification).

Answer (score 6):

This is by design per the markdown spec. Those are two unconnected lists.

You can however do this

```
1. List Item

   or

2. List item
```

1. List Item

   or
2. List item

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's an unfortunate trait of markdown.  You can get around it by indenting each entire list item by 4 spaces however.

1. This is a multi-paragraph list item.

   It has lots of teeny paragraphs.

   But there is a way around it...
2. It's not ideal, but it gets the job done!
3. Ta da!

(found this out from the [markdown reference on daringfireball](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a bug and it isn't. It appears to be by design. I can reproduce it here (edit to see the problem). If you hit enter after placing the second list item, then this problem goes away:

1. List item

   or
2. List item

Comment: If it's by design, then it's not a bug...